# Firebase user.getToken having stale value after signout

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following Firebase guide for authentication for the web (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Web), it works fine for most of the cases. However, if I log out of my Gmail account it still shows the data of the previously logged in user. The biggest challenge is `user.getToken()` is getting the old token. Has anyone faced similar issue? What would be the way to resolve it.

Here are the details ( please note it is not full-fledged application, I am exploring the authentication part before using in my web application)

1. In chrome browser, I log into my Gmail account
2. Go to my test web application/SPA, on the same browser
3. I see my details on the page (see the code below)

```js
var displayName = user.displayName;
            var email = user.email;
            var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            var photoURL = user.photoURL;
            var uid = user.uid;
            var providerData = user.providerData;
            user.getToken().then(function(accessToken) {
              document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
              document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
              document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                displayName: displayName,
                email: email,
                emailVerified: emailVerified,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                uid: uid,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                providerData: providerData
              }, null, '  ');
            });
```

4. Now I log out of my Gmail account
5. Go to test web application/SPA, still seeing the details
6. Go to chrome debugger and type `user.getToken()`, not null value is returned.

   Ideally, it should be null.

Appreciate any help.

Kind Regards

Comment: Signing out of your google account will not sign you out from your Firebase account. The user has to sign out explicitly from firebase. If you wish to sign out users from your app when they sign out from Google, then you should just use google sign in SDK.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks it worked for me.